# Getting NaN returned, unsure of why

Tags: c++, matrix, nan

I've scoured this code looking for why I get NaN as an output for summing the numbers of a 3-dimensional matrix. Here is the creation of the matrix, with each value being 3.6:

```
int dim = 100;
double ***my3DArray = new double**[dim];
for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
   my3DArray[i] = new double*[dim];
   for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
      my3DArray[i][j] = new double[dim];
      for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
         my3DArray[i][j][k] = 3.6;
      }
   }
}
```

And here is the summation:

```
long double sumArray(double*** a3DArray, int m, int n, int l) {
    long double sum;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
                sum += a3DArray[i][j][k];
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything special I should put in the `cout` command to make it not output as nan?
Or, does anyone see a glaring flaw? Thanks for any advice ahead of time.

Comment: initialize variable sum, long double sum = 0

Comment: What is `dsim` in this line: `for(int i = 0; i < dsim; i++)` ? It should be `dim`, no ?

Comment: @vishal Oh man thank you. I hate the simple mistakes.

Comment: @Paul R, Yeah, just a typo.

Comment: You also are not calling sumArray function from your main program

Comment: Stop scouring and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @beahtowel: there shouldn't be any typos - only ever copy and paste *actual code* - don't type up an approximation of your code, otherwise people waste time addressing non-existent problems (as in first two answers below).

Answer (score 1):

First, initialize variable sum in sumArray():

```
long double sum = 0;
```

In `main()` change `dism` to `dim`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
```

You have to call function from the `main()`:

```
sumArray(my3DArray,5,5,5); // random values
```

then, in order to print sum, do:

```
cout << sum;
```

after the first for loop, and at last make sure to `delete` your array, to free the memory

Comment: I'd also mention that there should be `return sum` in sumArray() after the closing brace of for (i .. m) loop.

Answer (score 0):

You get NaN because your sumArray function doesn't return any value.

**More info**

I built this using visual c++ .net,

1. sumArray doesn't return any value
2. Your 'dsim' variable should be written as 'dim'

---

**Fixed code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

long double sumArray(double*** a3DArray, int m, int n, int l) {
    long double sum;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
                sum += a3DArray[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int dim = 100;
    double ***my3DArray = new double**[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        my3DArray[i] = new double*[dim];
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            my3DArray[i][j] = new double[dim];
            for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
                my3DArray[i][j][k] = 3.6;
            }
        }
    }

    Double d = sumArray(my3DArray, 100, 100, 100);
    Console::WriteLine(d.ToString());   

    return 0;
}
```